# Mapping together symbols to values then returning a procedure to look up a value ( racket )

Tags: lambda, mapping, scheme, racket, procedure

I have been stumped with this for a few days now. Here is what I'm trying to do:

Let's say I have some list of symbols. Eg. '(A B C D). I want to map those symbols to values. Let's say my values are '(1 2 3 4).

Alright now here's the goal. I want to write a procedure that will return a procedure I can call again later. This is what I mean:

> (define get-mapped-value (map-together symbols values))
>
> (get-mapped-value 'A)

should return '1.

So far I have written a procedure to take two lists and "zip" them together, basically mapping values. So  given '(A B C D) and '(1 2 3 4) it will return ((A 1)(B 2)(C 3) and so on.

And I also wrote a procedure that given a symbol will return its mapped value. But I am having trouble tying this all up and being able to make that definition. My most recent attempt was:

```
(define map-together
  (case-lambda
    [(symbols vals) (lambda (cons lst (zip-together keys vals))]
    [(symbol) (find-mapped-value symbol)]
       
      )
    )
  )
```

but that just returns the zipped list.

Comment: And how's `find-mapped-value` going to work, if it doesn't have access to the association list? also notice: the association list should be built only _once_, there's no point to recreate it each and every time a key is searched

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The solution is a bit simpler than you imagine - as long as `find-mapped-value` is correctly implemented, this should work:

```
(define (map-together keys vals)
  (let ((alist (zip-together keys vals)))
    (lambda (key)
      (find-mapped-value key alist))))
```

Explanation: first, create an association list (called `alist`) using `zip-together`. The list will be the same for all searches, so we can enclose it outside of the returned procedure.

After that, return a procedure that takes care of finding the key in the association list, notice that I modified `find-mapped-value` - now it receives the search key and the association list.

Just for fun, another way to solve this would be using `assoc`, because that procedure *already* performs the job of `find-mapped-value`. Here's my take on the solution:

```
(define (map-together keys vals)
  (let ((alist (map list keys vals)))     ; same as zip-together
    (lambda (key)
      (cond ((assoc key alist) => second) ; similar to find-mapped-value
            (else #f)))))
```

Of course, a more efficient solution for large lists would be to use a hash table:

```
(define (map-together keys vals)
  (let ((mapping (make-hash (map cons keys vals))))
    (lambda (key)
      (hash-ref mapping key (const #f)))))
```

All of the above implementations work as expected, and in case the key is not present in the mapping, they'll return `#f`:

```
(define symbols '(A B C D))
(define  values '(1 2 3 4))
(define get-mapped-value (map-together symbols values))

(get-mapped-value 'A)
=> 1

(get-mapped-value 'F)
=> #f
```

Comment: Sorry about the delayed response. Thanks for the help. I'm going to have to dive into your answer more to fully understand every aspect of this problem. lambda is tripping me up.

Answer (score 0):

This is going to be close.

```
(define (map-together)
  (let ((a-list '()))
    (case-lambda
      [(symbols vals) 
       (begin (set! a-list (cons lst (zip-together keys vals)))
              a-list)]
      [(symbol) (find-mapped-value symbol)])))
```

Anyways the local variable should help. You would use it like so

(define alphebet-value (map-together))

(alphabet-value (list 'a 'b 'c 'c) (list 1 2 3 4))

(alphebet-value 'c)
-->3

Not sure it it's exactly if what you want. For large value you probably want to use a hash-table or red-black tree instead of an association list. Racket should have an implementation of both available in a modules somewhere.

This implementation the function will overwrite the old a-list if you call it with (symbols vals). If you want something that can append and update your a-list it gets a little trickier.

Answer (score 0):

Your `map-together` function needs to return a function that takes a symbol and returns a value.  The value returned will be based on a table mapping symbols to values.  As such:

```
(define (map-together symbols values)
  (let ((table (map cons symbols values)))
    (lambda (symbol)
      (cond ((assq symbol table) => cdr)
            (else #f)))))

> (define get-mapped-value (map-together '(a b c d) '(1 2 3 4)))
> (get-mapped-value 'a)
1
```

The mapping from symbols to values is implemented as a Scheme association list using `(map cons symbols values)`.  With that association list we can use `assq` to find the `pair` in the association; if such a pair exists, the `cdr` is the value.

Note that because the table doesn't change, we define the function-to-be-returned based on a  lexical variable `table` that we create outside of the `lambda`.